# Artix Linux with runit freezes at boot

Tags: boot, runit, artix-linux

I'm using Artix Linux with runit on my machine, and after I installed a new WiFi/Bluetooth combo card in my system via PCIe. I started having a random freeze during startup. It happens 1/3 times or so. The system hangs on a black scree with a white cursor in the top left corner. I tried switching to another tty to see if I can unfreeze it. But as soon as I switch, I can see the login prompt for a second, and then it goes back to black very quickly.

I'm not sure if it's related to the PCIe card, I just thought it's worth mentioning because the problem started happening just after I installed it.

My setup looks like this:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                             8:0    0 447,1G  0 disk  (My SSD)
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   300M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                                          8:2    0 431,8G  0 part  
│ └─luks-c1dec924-cacc-463a-b0b1-da15fd3791ad 254:0    0 431,8G  0 crypt / (5.11.1-artix1-1)
└─sda3                                          8:3    0    15G  0 part  
  └─luks-c86d3e5b-d4de-4e44-95b7-aae30d93e57c 254:1    0    15G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sdb                                             8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk  (My HDD)
├─sdb1                                          8:17   0    16M  0 part  (Windows UEFI partition)
├─sdb2                                          8:18   0 292,5G  0 part  (Windows 10)
├─sdb3                                          8:19   0   499M  0 part  
├─sdb4                                          8:20   0 185,9G  0 part  (NTFS backup partition)
└─sdb5                                          8:21   0 452,6G  0 part  (ext4 backup partition)
  └─luks-3e1e88b2-1dce-4602-88c4-6c0e6bc0afe5 254:2    0 452,6G  0 crypt /mnt/214cd7fa-1ddb-43d9-879b-f78152af9629
```

I took a look at the log files and found the following log repeating lots of time in `/var/log/auth.log` :

```
Mar  3 23:43:23 vibranium elogind[2226]: elogind is already running as PID 1305
Mar  3 23:43:24 vibranium elogind[2239]: elogind is already running as PID 1305
Mar  3 23:43:25 vibranium elogind[2249]: elogind is already running as PID 1305
Mar  3 23:43:26 vibranium elogind[2258]: elogind is already running as PID 1305
Mar  3 23:43:27 vibranium elogind[2273]: elogind is already running as PID 1305
Mar  3 23:43:28 vibranium elogind[2282]: elogind is already running as PID 1305
Mar  3 23:43:29 vibranium elogind[2291]: elogind is already running as PID 1305
Mar  3 23:43:30 vibranium elogind[2301]: elogind is already running as PID 1305
```

This is the only thing that seemed wrong in the logs. Everything else seems good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution to this.

When I looked at the output of `dmesg`, I found this.

```
[    0.242824] pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
[    0.242916] pci 0000:00:00.2: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[    0.242917] pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT A: not connected
[    0.242945] pci 0000:00:01.0: Adding to iommu group 0
[    0.242954] pci 0000:00:01.2: Adding to iommu group 0
[    0.242967] pci 0000:00:08.0: Adding to iommu group 1
[    0.242973] pci 0000:00:08.1: Adding to iommu group 1
[    0.242985] pci 0000:00:14.0: Adding to iommu group 2
[    0.242991] pci 0000:00:14.3: Adding to iommu group 2
[    0.243018] pci 0000:00:18.0: Adding to iommu group 3
[    0.243025] pci 0000:00:18.1: Adding to iommu group 3
```

I don't know what it is, so a quick google search and [I found this question in Linux Mint forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=329742#:%7E:text=Diego%2C%20California%2C%20USA-,Re%3A%20%22AMD%2DVi%3A%20Unable%20to%20read%2Fwrite,IOMMU%20perf%20counter%22%20at%20boot&text=Try%20adding%20iommu%3Dpt%20to,plan%20on%20running%20a%20VM.). The answer to which was to:

> Try adding `iommu=pt` to the end of the
> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line in `/etc/default/grub`;
> run `sudo update-grub` afterwards, then reboot.

That's what I did and sure enough... It worked! I'm no longer having any boot freezes.